# Need powershell script to zip files from T-SQL

Tags: sql, powershell, zip, sql-server-2014

For SQL Server 2014 on Windows Server 2012, I need to run a T-SQL command that runs a script in PowerShell to compress files. This is not a straightforward zip, so a file called `1204444.sav` will need to be renamed based upon a variable I acquire in T-SQL statement (I can handle this), so this file may be renamed ~TEMPDSJDKSS823918

Comment: What does your code look like so far?

Comment: sorry missed this not a powershell guy just dba/devloper/everything else.  I have the variable defined in the code so file name to change and file name to zip to are done,  anything special about calling the PS code from tsql examples look pretty straight forward

Comment: I believe that you should take a look at xp_cmdshell -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 . First, you need to construct command line with all needed argument and then pass it as argument.

Comment: i get the part about command shell like I said weakness on PS side

Comment: I refer the honorable gentleman to my initial question, posted some 60 minutes ago.

Comment: OK from Powershell I can run command compress-archive -Path c:\media\dm1210.csv -DestinationPath c:\media\dmtim.zip.   That works fine, from tsql I run exec xp_cmdshell 'powershell ""compress-archive -Path c:\media\dm1210.csv -DestinationPath c:\media\dmtim.zip""' which does not run

Comment: also tried this exec xp_cmdshell 'Powershell.exe  -noprofile -command "Compress-Archive -Path c:\media\dm1210.csv -DestinationPath c:\media\dmtim.zip"'

Comment: Keeps kicking back error message about Compress-Archive : The term 'Compress-Archive' is not recognized as the name

Answer (score 0):

I cannot speak for the SQL side of things, but here is how you can create a ZIP file from PowerShell:

```
powershell.exe -Command "Compress-Archive -Path C:\path\to\file\to\compress.txt" -DestinationPath "C:\path\to\archive.zip"
```

This requires PowerShell 5.0. You can check your installed PowerShell version by opening an interactive window and checking the `$PSVersion` variable.